# How do you resolve 'Font was not found' error in visualWorks 8.1?

Tags: pdf, fonts, smalltalk, visualworks

I have been using the report4pdf(bob nemec) package to generate reports as PDFs. Everything goes well except when I am trying to have some nice cell padding on the right.Thought an update would fix that.

So I connected to the public repository and updated the following:

Report4PDF 1.4.0.1
(comments said this was made to match with PDF Development 1.4.3.0 and Font Development 1.3.3.2. So updated those too).

However when I update and run the code it says,' Font not Found'.
Sure enough, when I run the debugger and 'inspect' on the self loadedFonts part from the debugger:

```
^self loadedFonts at: aSymbolOrFilenameString ifAbsent: [
        FontNotFound raiseSignal: aSymbolOrFilenameString , ' was not found']
```

where: A symbolOrFilenameString=  #'Helvetica-Bold'

As I opened the dictionary object, the font was there. Its just that the key didn't match. I am guessing the update changed all the keys except this one.
Anyway I hope you guys can help me out.

Thanks in Advance!

UPDATE 1:

Hi Bob! So I ran the ifNil block on the loadedFonts. But I hit a new error. It says: OrderedCollection(Collection)>>notFoundError. 
So its trying to get something from 
Graphic.Fonts.OpenType.CmapSubtable class>>classFor::`

## The code being:

```
 classFor: formatInteger 
^self allSubclasses detect: [:sc | sc subclasses isEmpty and: [ sc formatNumber = formatInteger]]
```

======= 
where formatInteger is 4.

[image: ScreenShot of Debugger]

Comment: A quick and dirty fix would consist in replacing the argument of `at:` with `(aSymbolOrFilenameString copyWithout: $-) asSymbol`. But I'm not sure this is the kind of solution you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah. I was looking for a more elegant solution but I will give this a try if nothing else works... thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Font class>>loadedFonts changed in the latest 'Fonts Basics' package, and Report4PDF was changed to use the new names. However, the LoadedFonts class variable in Graphics.Fonts.Font is initialized on the first reference. To get the new list, after loading the latest code, you need to run the ifNil: [] block in Font class>>loadedFonts.

In my image, with the latest code loaded, #'Helvetica-Bold' is defined in LoadedFonts.

Comment: Hi Bob! So  I ran the ifNil block on the loadedFonts. But I hit a new error. It says: OrderedCollection(Collection)>>notFoundError.
<><><><><>

So its trying to get something from Graphic.Fonts.OpenType.CmapSubtable class>>classFor::
<><><><><
The code being:
================
    classFor: formatInteger
 ^self allSubclasses detect: [:sc |
  sc subclasses isEmpty and: [
  sc formatNumber = formatInteger]]
=======
where formatInteger is 4.
==============
I don't know where to proceed from here. Apologies for the poor formatting. I can seem to get the coding right in comments.